# Extensive quoting, is there an issue?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copyright — quoting cookbook versus referencing](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/copyright-quoting-cookbook-versus-referencing)

I've just [edited](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9072/what-flour-and-technique-do-i-need-for-hand-pulled-noodles/9084#9084) an answer. All I did was copypaste quotes from the referenced website. I suppose there is no problem with that as the original link is still in place. Do I (we) need to ask explicit permission to quote?

Comment: In this case I would say that it probably *doesn't* qualify as fair use because it represents the answer content in its entirety, rather than being quoted sparsely for context. I would turn the ingredients block into a point-form list (no quoting) and try to summarize the second part.